# How do I log the raw HTTP headers with a PHP script?

Tags: php, http, header

I'm using a cURL script to send POST data through a proxy to a script and I want to see what raw HTTP headers the cURL script is sending. List of things I've tried:

- `echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)` gives no output.
- `file_get_contents('php://input')` gets some HTTP headers but not all.
- `print_r($_SERVER)` also gets some HTTP headers but not all (I know this because there should be a X-Forwarded-For header and there isn't)
- Printing all superglobals ($_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST, $_FILES etc) still doesn't show the raw HTTP headers.
- `http_get_request_headers()`, `apache_request_headers()`, `$http_response_header`, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` aren't outputting everything.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

Turn on CURLOPT_HEADER, not CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, then split on \r\n\r\n (which is where the header ends) with a maximum split count of 2 :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.yahoo.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result !== false) {
    $split_result = split("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    $header = $split_result[0];
    $body = $split_result[1];
    /** Process here **/
} else {
   /** Error handling here **/
}
```

Comment: this is basically right except you should use explode instead of split and it doesn't account for multiple headers (such as a 301/302 redirect)

Answer (score 1):

You need to also set the `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` option:

> CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT
>   TRUE to track the
>   handle's request string.
>   Available
>   since PHP 5.1.3. The CURLINFO_ prefix
>   is intentional.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

The following works:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

Comment: @php: ah, so you actually want to know what the proxy is sending, not what curl is sending. you probably need to log that on the proxy itself or the remote server. curl doesn't know what headers your proxy is adding

Answer (score 0):

If you running as a module on Apache then  [apache_request_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)() does what you need.

For just about any other architecture you'll only be able to pick out the stuff which is recorded in $_SERVER or you'll need to find some way to record the information using the web server config.

Comment: You must be a fan of C.